# Update a column of one table with a column of another table 2 without relationship

Tags: oracle, sql-update

I have a table `A` with two columns where column `NR` is empty

```
Fruit--------------NR
Apple 
Peach
Strawberry
Orange
```

and table `B` with one column `NR`

```
NR
121
314
422
756
```

I have to insert values from NR column from table B to NR column in table A
Order of data is not important. I want only to copy all values.

Comment: Huh?  If there is no relationship, then how do you know which NR in B goes to A?  Does not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probalble the simplest solution is to create a new table and populate it with the *column binded* data.

You will use a join based on the `row_number`s defined for both tables in *some* order. Note, that the requirement is, that both tables has the same number of rows, otherwise some column from the *longer* table will be ignored.

The query

```
insert into new_a (fruit,nr) 
with fruit as (
select fruit, 
row_number() over (order by fruit) rn from a),
nr as (
select nr,
row_number() over (order by nr) rn
from b)
select fruit, nr from fruit join nr
on fruit.rn = nr.rn;
```

In other words, you must **first define the sense, i.e. ordering in both tables**, the you can perform the *column UNION*.